# find string in file and add content with bash and sed

Tags: string, bash, sed

I'm trying to add a string with a bunch of filenames (which include directory slashes) to a file after a specific search string.

I've created my input text like this:

```
for f in /tmp/et/*.rules; do 
    #STRING+=`basename "$f"`$'\n'; 
    STRING+=$'include $RULE_PATH/et/'`basename "$f"`$'\n'
done
```

Which makes `$STRING` equal:

```
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-activex.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-attack_response.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-botcc.portgrouped.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-botcc.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-chat.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-ciarmy.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-compromised.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-current_events.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-deleted.rules
include $RULE_PATH/et/emerging-dns.rules
```

and my `sed` command to add the `$STRING` content looks like this:

```
sed -i.bak 's!^#EMERGING\ THREATS\ RULESET.*$!& \n'"$STRING"'!' snort.conf
```

this is looking for the text `#EMERGING THREATS RULESET` and adding `$STRING` on a new line after the matched text.

I had to change the default `sed` delimiters to something else because the default `/` were conflicting with the directory paths in my `$STRING`.  Now, the problem is that I'm getting an error from `sed` stating:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 82: unterminated `s' command
```

I know this has gotta be a simple problem with string manipulation or something regarding the quotes, but I've tried lots of combinations here and can't figure it out...

Comment: Can you show value of `$STRING`?

Comment: I did.  its the excerpt with all the `include`'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok use this approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
> _tmp
for f in /tmp/et/*.rules; do 
    echo $'include $RULE_PATH/et/'`basename "$f"`$'\n' >> _tmp
done

sed -i.bak '/^#EMERGING THREATS RULESET/r _tmp' snort.conf
```

Which basically stores your output in a temporary file and uses that temporary file to replace content in sed command after your search pattern.

Comment: I believe the issue is with multi-line variable. +1 for resolving it.

Comment: Just realized you maxed out on points. Will upvote at midnite GMT to compensate! `;)`

Comment: Thanks you so much for being so considerate Jaypal! Yes I maxed out couple of hours back for today.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You are using incorrect delimiter:</strike>

```
sed -i.bak 's!^#EMERGING\ THREATS\ RULESET.*$/& \n'"$STRING"'!' snort.conf
                                             ^
                                             |
---------------------------------------------
```

So it seems your issue is unescaped newline. You cannot have an unescaped newline in `sed` replacement text (`$STRING` in your example). `sed` scripting uses the newline just like the shell does, to terminate a command.

If you need a newline in the replacement text, you need to precede it with a backslash. Alternatively, if you're using `gnu sed` and do not care about portability to other sed implementations, you can replace a newline with a `\n`, in the replacement text (all posix-compliant seds allow this in the regular expression, but not in the replacement as it is a gnu extension). Since your embedded newline is in a variable, this approach will not work for you.

So you can either do as [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23094147/970195) has shown in his answer, or alternatively use an `awk` solution:

```
awk -v patt="$STRING" '/^#EMERGING THREATS RULESET/{print $0;print patt;next}1' snort.conf >tmp && mv tmp snort.conf
```

Not that this would need `GNU awk`.

Comment: yes, very sharp eyes, but I changed it `!` and it still isn't working

Comment: @sadmicrowave Are you getting the same error message or a new one?

Comment: @sadmicrowave Have updated the answer to reflect the true issue.